# MVC - Passing generic model to a method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

I have a function `FillPdf()` which I am using to fill an editable pdf. For now I have defined its parameter type but I have three different forms each having different model so I want is my this `FillPdf()` receives the respective model and use its data.How to achieve this.

**FillPdf.cs**

```
  public static bool FillPdf(M2HDetail m2HUserDetails)
    {
        try
        {
            if (PdfFileSettingViewModel.M2HAuthorizationFormLocation == null)
                return false;
            var pdfReader = new PdfReader(PdfFileSettingViewModel.M2HAuthorizationFormLocation);
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (DictionaryEntry de in pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields)
            {
                sb.Append(de.Key.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            var newFile = Path.Combine(PdfFileSettingViewModel.TempFolderLocation, string.Format("{0}_{1}.pdf", "M2HForm",SessionItems.UserId));
            System.IO.File.Copy(PdfFileSettingViewModel.M2HAuthorizationFormLocation, newFile);

            var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create));

            var pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
            var totalFields = pdfFormFields.Fields.Count;

            var myParams = new List<string>();

            #region # SetPdfFields #

            pdfFormFields.SetField("Text1", m2HUserDetails.LastName);
            pdfFormFields.SetField("Text2", m2HUserDetails.FirstName);
            pdfStamper.FormFlattening = false;

            #endregion

            pdfStamper.Close();

            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(PdfFileSettingViewModel.TempFolderLocation);
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(file);
            }

            return false;
        }

    }
```

**Caller function**

```
 public ActionResult AuthorizationForm(M2HDetail model)
    {
      var isFillPdfSuccess = PdfFiller.FillPdf(model);
      return View();
     }
```

Now I want that I can use the same pdf method for my other form like this:

```
 public ActionResult AuthorizationFormHippa(HippaAuthForm model)
    {
      var isFillPdfSuccess = PdfFiller.FillPdf(model);
      return View();
     }
```

Also I want that my pdf method could have parameter as model like this:

```
  public static bool FillPdf(ModelForm model)
{
 }
```

Please suggest how to achieve this.As I can have more than 3 forms in future and each time I have to write the same method just with different parameter type.

Comment: Why don' t you make your models inherit from the same base class/interface?

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would create a generic interface

```
public interface IPdfContent
{
    // Add your common properties here
}
```

Then get all of your models to implement this interface

```
public class HippaAuthForm : IPdfContent
{
}
```

Now for your `PdfFill` class you can do this:

```
public static bool FillPdf(IPdfContent m2HUserDetails)
{
    ...
}
```

Because `FillPdf` is now expecting the `Interface` you can now pass it anyone who implements that `Interface`. This now allows you to create new models without having to do any work.

Just implement the interface!

This also will allow you to Mock out your models and you can unit test a bit easier since you will now have DI in place.

Comment: but in this case I have to declare all my properties of both models in Interface as I am not able to access them so what's the benefit of having interface if I need to declare all properties and in it and then again implement in the respective model.Please suggest how to avoid this

Comment: Yes, you would declare your properties in the Interface, then implement the interface. You can then pass in the interface and the `FillPdf` method now knows about the implemented properties. I do not see why this is a problem. The only way you want where you do absolutely no work, is to make the method a generic and then pass in a generic. But for maintainability and extensibility I would use an interface. If you do not understand their purpose, please do some reading up on them.

Comment: @JamieRees Your problem = the reason why interfaces/abstract classes where invented. If You don't understand benefits of that - make some reading, like really.

Comment: @MajkeloDev I'm sorry, I do not understand the purpose of your comment? Can you please explain.

Comment: It was a comment which was approving Your answer. It was a mistake i wanted to use @rupinder18 in mistake i took You. Sorry. Your approach with interface is the one and only good solution

Answer (score -1):

I think your title has a clue on the solution to your problem.

All you gotta do is,

1. Create a generic model, let us call it `PdfDetailsModel`. This model class should have information that you must have in `FillPdf()` method.
2. Create specific model class deriving from `PdfDetailsModel`. This specific class will contain additional information required to serve the request. Let us call it `PdfDetailsHippaAuthModel`.
3. Pass `PdfDetailsHippaAuthModel` to `FillPdf` method that accepts base class object.
4. Since `FillPdf()` depends on the base class, it is happy with any derived instance.